# How do I minimize a javafx stage on close to the system tray?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have an application with 2 stages, I dont want users to close the 2nd stage, just iconify it.

At present I am using the oncloseRequest handler to minimize the window -

```
secondaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    secondaryStage.setIconified(true);
    event.consume();
});
```

I would like to show an icon in the system tray when a user closes the window. And the user should be able to reopen the window from the tray.

Also, how do I ensure when the primary stage is closed, the 2nd stage also closes?

Comment: There is no build-in capability for that in javafx. This can be done (in Windows) with some tools to iconify applications to system tray. Only thing is in awt https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html And if you speak german, there is a nice guide to make it happen to javafx: http://blog.essential-bytes.de/wie-man-javafx-applikationen-in-das-system-tray-verbannt/ or in english from jewelsea: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a

Comment: Thanks! Also how do I close the 2nd window when the primary stage is closed?

Answer (score 8):

Set the following property in start method

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

Then set the on close event

```
secondaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    // Your code here
});
```

To make a system tray try following code:

Original document link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

```
    //Check the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

    URL url = System.class.getResource("/images/new.png");
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);

    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // Create a pop-up menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
    Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
    MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
    MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
    MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
    MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Add components to pop-up menu
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(cb1);
    popup.add(cb2);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(displayMenu);
    displayMenu.add(errorItem);
    displayMenu.add(warningItem);
    displayMenu.add(infoItem);
    displayMenu.add(noneItem);
    popup.add(exitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

Example system tray image:

[image: System tray program example]

To invoke method of Javafx from awt event handler you may follw the following way:

```
yourAwtObject.addActionListener(e -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> primaryStage.show());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how do I ensure when the primary stage is closed, the 2nd stage
>   also closes?

You can use something like this to close the secondary stage when the primary stage is closed:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent we) -> {
    secondaryStage.close();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just iconify the secondaryStage because of the other onCloseRequest handler?

Comment: You could add an if statement to your secondary onCloseRequest handler that checks if the primary stage is being closed or not